# Disable the ability to remove database volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a virtual machine with several compose files serving different applications.

I'm using docker volumes to store many things, such as files which cannot be embedded in the containers (large data or media files for example) or, most importantly, (postgres) databases.

I'm not the only one with access to this machine.

Therefore, I would like to tell `docker-compose down -v` to **not** affect the database volumes in order to avoid a catastrophic event.

Same thing with `docker system prune -a` or any other potentially harmful commands.

Is this possible? Or would you generally recommend to not store databases in docker volumes?

Comment: Anyone who can run any `docker` command has, or can trivially get, root access to the whole system; you can't limit what `docker` commands they can run, what host directories they can bind-mount, or what volumes they can delete.

Comment: Hmm, okay. That means I have to set up a database on the host machine but I never succeeded connecting to it from the containers.

Comment: A remote database is a valid option too.  Kubernetes may be excessive for your setup, but if not, its role-based access control (RBAC) system can limit users to specific namespaces, so one user couldn't delete another's storage (PersistentVolumeClaims).